# php, how to insert my friends avatars from twitter to my web page?

Tags: php, twitter, get

i would like to place all my friends / followers from twitter to my webpage?
no messages or timestamps, just the pictures.

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the basic steps involved after authenticating (see other questions/tutorials for that. No sense in repeating those steps here):

- Call <strike>[statuses/friends](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554749/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3a-statuses%C2%A0friends)</strike> to get list of your friends
- Call <strike>[statuses/followers](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554748/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3a-statuses%C2%A0followers)</strike> to get list of your followers
- Loop through lists, grabbing `profile_image_url` from each user
- Place URI into your web page.

**Edit:**

As noted by abraham, the above methods are deprecated so it is recommended to use an approach that utilizes:

- [GET friends/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/friends/ids)
- [GET followers/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/followers/ids)
- [GET users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/GET/users/lookup)

Comment: [GET statuses/friends](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/friends) and [GET statues/followers](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/followers) are both deprecated and should not be used. Instead use [GET friends/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/friends/ids), [GET followers/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/followers/ids), and [GET users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/GET/users/lookup).

Comment: Thanks, abraham. I've updated the answer to include that info.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at one of the available libraries? http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php